# uwfmgr does not function in 32bit system

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, security

I have to Switch from fbwfmgr to uwfmgr (because of switching from Windows XP to Windows 10) but every time when I do some Change so that uwfmgr has to reset it the Computer "Crashes" and I have to rewrite the SSD. (Blue Display with the reason "Stop code: KMODE ECEPTION NOT HANDLED" and "What failed: uwfs.sys")

But the same configuration works on a 64bit system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it a 32 bit or a 64 bit driver? I'd recon you might be trying to run a 64 bit driver on 32 bit... which seems like a potential explaination.

Comment: I am trying it on 32 driver - the computer doesn't function used all the other time Windows XP but now I need some features of Windows 10 so that I updated it (and now its anyway 32 bit..) but it doesn't function with the named error.

(On a new windows 10 with 64 bit instead of 32bit the problem doesn't exists)